# Search and display database using php

Tags: php, mysql

A webpage in which when we enter id their location is displayed from database. All the location in location columns shows up when I search for a specific location.

I was asked to create a webpage in which when an individual enter a code his location shows up. I'm not able to fix this problem. 'id' is the name of individual and fname is the column in which location is. DAta is the name of database.

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` LIKE '%$qname%'"); 


    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == "0"){
        $output = '<h2>No result found!</h2>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $s = $row['fname']; 
                $output .= '<div><h2>'.$s.'</div></h2><br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="search.php">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="query">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
        </form>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect only one location that is specified to show up not all the locations in the database.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You do not have a variable called `$qname`!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your query, try to do as bellow
change:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` LIKE '%$qname%'
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id LIKE '%$qname%'
```

Comment: You haven't suggested any changes, not to mention that you have not explained it.